# Laravel 4, model in workbench package, Eloquent not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to develop a package, but am stuck with the Eloquent model part. I have got a package in the workbench like `workbench/vendor/workbench/src/models`

My models are like

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Shop\Models;

/**
 * A catalog
 */
class Catalog extends \Eloquent {

    // Define the database
    protected $table = 'catalogs';

    // Mass assignment restriction
    protected $fillable = array('name');

}

?>
```

My problem is the import of the Eloquent Namespace which is not that proper i guess, because if i run a UnitTest with PHPUnit it simply fails with `Class 'Eloquent' not found`

Is this because of the Autoloading in composer? An extract from the composer file:

```
"require" : {
    "php" : ">=5.3.0",
    "illuminate/support" : "4.0.x",
    "illuminate/database": "4.0.x"
},
"autoload" : {
    "classmap" : [
        "src/controllers",
        "src/models",
        "src/migrations",
        "src/database/seeds"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Vendor\\Shop" : "src/"
    }
},
```

Comment: i guess its because it is only importing the support part of illuminate

Comment: i updated the requires but still have the same problem, in the docs the always extend `Eloquent` but not `Eloquent\Model`, if i use model this works, but why is this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tests aren't running from the root of your project (where `artisan` is) then they're most likely not bootstrapping the application prior to the tests run. What this means is that none of the aliases defined in `app/config/app.php` are actually defined. That's what `Eloquent` is, it's an alias which points at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

There's a few things you can do here.

1. Use a package called [testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench). I've not used this but from what I can tell it depends on the entire `laravel/framework` repository. I have mixed feelings about this. But essentially this package runs a setup similar to how your Laravel application is setup during the tests. This package *might* allow you to continue extending `Eloquent`, although I can't confirm or deny this.
2. Extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` directly. This is probably much easier as you already depend on the `illuminate/database` repository. The only downside here is that if you release this package and someone has swapped out the `Eloquent` alias with their own custom extension of Eloquent then it won't be applied to your package. Because your package is extending the Eloquent directly and not using the alias it's not as flexible.

In the end it depends on the circumstances of your package. If it's just going to be used by you internally then I'd probably go with option 2. If not, try option 1, and if it fails revert to option 2.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: We will use this internally, so option2 is fine for me. But another thing: i was not able yet to start the unit tests from outside the package (because you said the application is not bootstrapped). If i want to bootstrap the application i have to either get phpunit to load the package test or load the application from within the package test?

Comment: Yeah your tests need to run from within the package directory (obviously). The problem here is that this code is pretty much isolated from the rest of the application. If you look at the `phpunit.xml` file from the main application you'll see it uses the `bootstrap/autoload.php` and not `vendor/autoload.php`. That's where the Laravel application is bootstrapped. Also, application tests extend the `TestCase` in `app/tests`, which in turns extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`.

Comment: i simply added the test directory to the main config file. I will try bootstrapping the application in the package, i guess this would be the better solution, even if the best solution would be if i wouldnt have to care about this. I saw a lot of packages dont use test at all and the lack of simplicity makes it even harder to write tests. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Lewis mentioned in the comments, the main issue here is where phpunit is bootstrapping. If you're developing your Laravel package in the `workbench` folder with a fresh installation of Laravel, it's pretty safe to assume that your package is not framework agnostic and will solely depend on Laravel.

As such it isn't "necessary" to have the unit tests executed in the package directory exclusively from everything else. That is, assuming we're not worried about some sort of CI process getting screwed up, but there are probably some workarounds. I'll research this a bit more.

So I opted for a 3rd option. Just extend your package's tests from `TestCase` as you would normally.

`class MyAwesomeTest extends TestCase {}`

Then at the command line, `cd` into the root of the parent Laravel project and run phpunit with your workbench directory as an argument.

`phpunit workbench/vender/my-package/tests/`

That will execute all your package's unit tests with the parent Laravel's bootstrap thus giving you access to all the awesome Laravel unit testing help you're used to.

Comment: we are heavily depending on our CI, the tests should be directory agnostic, when me move our package out of the workbench we simply change the include directories in our main test config file. i feel this is the easiest solution for us even though this should not be necessary at all, but thx for the idea